# is this how you would link invoice to patients and visits in a simple ERD?

Tags: key, entity, relationship, erd

So, a patient can have multiple visits, and are invoiced once per month. This means that multiple visits can also be in one invoice. Is this how you would link these three tables together, or am I missing something completely. Any advice on this is greatly appreciated thank you!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAFIF.jpg

I tried the erd in the screenshot link and I think it makes sense to me, or this issue could be alot more complicated involving join tables too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your ERD makes sense:

- An invoice can be for several visits, but a visit can be on only one invoice. The `invoice_id` as FK and PK implement the one-to-many relationship.
- An invoice is for one patient, and one patient can receive several invoices.  The `patient_id` as PK and FK  implement the one to many relationship (this FK should have the constraint `NOT NULL` in the database).

There is a potential problem however:

- Your diagram says that every visit has an invoice. This is not realistic in a real life-scenario: the invoice does not exist at the moment of the visit; it is only created at the end of month when all the visits to be invoiced are known. So for a temporary period, the visits can exist without invoice. The diagram should be explicit on the optional nature of the invoice  (`--|o-` in the [crow's foot ERD notation](https://vertabelo.com/blog/crow-s-foot-notation/))
- Since visits may exist temporarily without an invoice,  your system must be able to find the patient which will have to be invoiced for this visit.  This means that there should be a one-to-many relationship between the patient (mandatory) and the visit.  Perhaps it's there and is cut on the screenshot.